# How to get the percentage difference during group by stage of hive SQL if possible?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a query which does grouping by day and name and count the number of rows for that group.

Below is the data which I get after group by phase.

```
name  day           count
A     2019-01-01    120
A     2019-01-02    127
B     2019-01-01    756
B     2019-01-02    125
C     2019-01-02    102
D     2019-01-01    57
```

I want to find out percentage difference in counts of name against each day.

Is it possible to achieve this in query itself and send the percentage and name as query output?

i.e. 
((today's count - previous day's count)/today's count) * 100

```
A = ((127 - 120) / 127)*100 = 5.51%
B = ((125 - 756) / 125)*100 = -504.8%
C = ( (102 - 0) / 102)*100 = 100%
D = check divide by zero --> if true = 100%
```

Output expected:

```
A, 5.51
B, -504.8
C, 100
D, 100
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is a missing day?

Comment: Gordon sir, Thanks for pointing out. For missing day, i have put the example C and D, i can not think of the other scenarios as of now but for a period of 3 or more days this problem will become more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT *, 
  100.0 * (count - LAG(count, 1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY day))/cnt AS result
FROM tab;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=30cc13500fa12d03503567839270b539)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lukasz